# Can the password_verify algorithm be changed to SHA1?

Tags: php, mysqli

My accounts are created via game, not by register.php, and game allows me only to register via SHA1 and I want to modify the login system to take password hashes in SHA1. I don't know how to modify verifypassword into SHA1.

I want login.php to read SHA1 passwords.

For example, in MySQL:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`
     WHERE username='$username' and password='".sha1($password)."'";
```

Code:

```
 <?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement

        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        $hashed_password = $row['password'];
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the username to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would you want to use SHA to start with?

Comment: You mention SHA1 but then you're using `password_hash/password_verify`, I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I don't. I used SHA before, now I want to modify it with the hash made by my login and register script, but in game script I don't know what variable to use instead of sha1.  I trie dto put $stmt  but it didn't work.

Comment: I want to modify sha1  with password_hash, and I don't know what should i rewrite instead of SHA1

Comment: or, how can I modify the login.php to get SHA1 password? @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: question simplified.

Comment: Pro tips for asking questions: (1) make titles here succinct, free of any chat and please-help begging, (2) avoid txtspk at all costs, since "please" is not hard to type, (3) use a username that is not itself begging, or indicative of a user who does not intend to stick around after their question is answered.

Comment: The answer to your question is that `password_verify` will not work with any algorithms other than the ones that PHP provides in that system (Bcrypt and a much newer one). You will need to do the hashing/salting manually, and you'll need to understand the format that was used to hash the passwords originally. Are they salted?

Comment: in cell, it's shown salted, ex 956f928d63881f728748cbd22ef534d26e92a2f5

Comment: @pleasehelp It's a little bit unclear what you are trying to do? Do you have SHA1 hashes in your database and you want to switch to password_verify/hash()? Keep in mind that you cannot 'convert' a hash of one type to a hash of the other type.

Comment: @Progman My game can register only with sha1 unsalted, and I made an login system with sha1,  but it's on mysql  and it's depricated so I tried to make it on PDO, like it's upstair, but on PDO i couldn't translate POST password  as sha1. If  you want, I can post my other script to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: @pleasehelp using the `sha1()` is not deprecated, so you can use it in PHP as well as in MySQL. However you shouldn't use sha1 for hashing the user passwords, but since you have no other choice (unless you change the game code) you have to use it anyway.

Comment: @Progman I was usingmysql, and on localhost code works perfectly, but on webhost it doesn't header and gives errors. That's why I wanted to create new login system.